# Using Aspose.Cells for .NET to read/write file's "Version number"

Tags: aspose-cells

An existing Excel file has a version number:

[image]

How do you read/write this version number using the Aspose.Cells API?

I did not find this in the documentation or when debugging the Workbook object.

Comment: is it the thing you are looking http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Get+the+Version+Number+of+the+Application+that+Created+the+Excel+Document

Comment: No, that's the Excel version, the version number in the screenshot is manually set, the goal is simply to be able to check it and read/write it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible to get this version number information using Aspose.Cells APIs from your excel file. However, I am unable to create such a file with version number using Microsoft Excel manually.

Please post this question in Aspose.Cells forum along with your sample excel file so that we could look into it and provide you a sample code to read/write this version number.

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*